# Mysql: Multiple where query

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I've got a table for storing customers choices regarding products.

It stores a customer number, product number and whether it's a yes or no thanks on the product. We're storing yes/no because the customer must make a choice on all products so that we can check if they've made all choices.

```
Customer | Product | Status
---------------------------
12345    | 1       | 0
12345    | 2       | 1
12345    | 3       | 1
12345    | 4       | 0
12345    | 5       | 1
23456    | 1       | 1
23456    | 2       | 0
23456    | 3       | 1
23456    | 4       | 1
23456    | 5       | 0
```

---

What I want to do is check which customers has chosen a specific set of products.
That could be something like `select * from choices where product = 1 and product = 3 group by customer` but then I must also query products with `status = 1`

Is there a way to solve this in a query or will I have to resort to a couple of calls to some PHP?

Comment: Condition product = 1 and product = 3 will give you zero rows, because product can't be 1 and 3 at the same time.

Comment: Should note that it's a false example, more like a "whish it worked like this".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
select customer 
from choices 
where status = 1 and product in (1,3)
group by customer
having count(distinct product) = 2
```

Comment: And `having count` would be the number of products I want to match, i guess? `1,3,6,16,17` would be `= 5`, correct?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DISTINCT a.customer
FROM choices a, choices b
WHERE a.customer = b.customer
AND a.product = 1
AND b.product = 3;
```

Doing this also allows you to put more complicated logic in later on: if you wanted everyone who purchased product 1 in 2012, and product 2 in 2013, you can add extra conditions in the where clause to filter for those.